# How to get window title in windows from shell

Tags: windows, shell

I can set title via windows shell using command `title some string`
but how can I get the title of some process?

I tried command `tasklist /v`, but my title is very, very long, that's why I receive only partial title. Also I was thinking about wmic utility, but can't find desired flag.

Comment: Pipe the output of `tasklist` to a text file?

Comment: What is wmic utility?

Comment: Nevermind, I just piped the output to a text file. The title is still truncated. AutoHotkey can achieve what you want, however. Give me a bit to write a script for the job. :)

Answer (score 10):

Nowadays shell is Powershell:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.mainWindowTitle} | Format-Table Id, Name, mainWindowtitle -AutoSize
```

and for title of selected proces:

```
(Get-Process -id 8748 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).MainWindowTitle
```

Comment: Fast and well working solution.

Comment: Seems to miss more types of windows compared to tasklist

Answer (score 9):

The script below shows that `tasklist /v /FO:CSV` does not truncate long window titles and *independently* solves two tasks:

- *Part 1* displays all *useful* window titles along with image names and PIDs in `csv` format; `findstr` is used to narrow down output to *really* useful titles.
- *Part 2* displays PID and title of the command prompt window where the script was executed from (*my own `cmd`*).

**Script**:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Part 1: ALL USEFUL WINDOW TITLES
echo(
set "_myExcludes=^\"conhost ^\"dwm ^\"nvxdsync ^\"nvvsvc ^\"dllhost ^\"taskhostex"
for /F "tokens=1,2,8,* delims=," %%G in ('
  tasklist /V /fo:csv ^| findstr /V "%_myExcludes%"
                                        ') do (
    if NOT "%%~J"=="N/A" echo %%G,%%~H,%%J
)

rem Part 2: MY OWN cmd WINDOW TITLE
echo(
set "_myTitleTail= - %~0"
for /F "tokens=1,2,8,* delims=," %%G in ('
  tasklist /V /fo:csv ^| findstr /I /C:"%_myTitleTail%"
                                        ') do (
    set "_myTitleBatch=%%~J"
    set "_myCmdPIDno=%%~H"
)
call set "_myCmdTitle=%%_myTitleBatch:%_myTitleTail%=%%"
echo _myCmdPIDno=%_myCmdPIDno%
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  echo _myCmdTitle=!_myCmdTitle!
ENDLOCAL
```

**Output**:

```
==> TITLE ...but my title is very, very long, that's why I receive only partial title. Also 
I was thinking about wmic utility, but can't find desired flag!!!

==> .\SU\378790.bat

"Image Name",PID,"Window Title"
"VDeck.exe",4032,"VIA HD Audio Deck"
"chrome.exe",5760,"How to get window title in windows from shell - Super User - Google Chrom
e"
"powershell_ise.exe",5568,"Windows PowerShell ISE"
"cmd.exe",4980,"...but my title is very, very long, that's why I receive only partial title.
 Also I was thinking about wmic utility, but can't find desired flag!!! - .\SU\378790.bat"
"PSPad.exe",5108,"378790.bat"
"cmd.exe",3888,"d:\bat"
"cmd.exe",5648,"Administrator: Command Prompt"

_myCmdPIDno=4980
_myCmdTitle=...but my title is very, very long, that's why I receive only partial title. Als
o I was thinking about wmic utility, but can't find desired flag!!!

==>
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (helpful particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (special page) [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- (`SET %variable:StrToFind=NewStr%`) [Variable Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)

Comment: Seems to miss some types of windows (in my case a windows error message)

Answer (score 5):

[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) can help you achieve this. Let's write a script that outputs the process and titles of all open windows to **stdout**:

```
WinGet, windows, list

Loop, %windows%
{
    id := windows%A_Index%
    WinGet, process, ProcessName, ahk_id %id%
    WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %id%
    FileAppend, %process% %title%`n, *
}

ExitApp
```

**Compile** the script to get a portable **.exe**.

Now, we can run the following from the Windows command line:

```
MyScript.exe | more
```

### Example:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: is there any way to do it without AutoKey? Don't want to use external utility

Comment: Hmm. After comparing the output of `tasklist /v` and my script, there is discrepancy. My script only picks up processes which register a window, while tasklist seems to get it's information elsewhere. I'll see if I can figure out how to get the same outputs.