# Find all window titles of application through command line

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, process

In Windows if I want to list all instances (and window titles) of a given application from the command line I run this command:

```
tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq notepad.exe" /v
```

However I can't do the same thing for applications such as LibreOffice. For example no matter how many different Writer windows I may have open, there always is only one `soffice.bin` and one `soffice.exe` process. Using the `tasklist` command I can only see one window title associated with `soffice.bin` process.

Same thing happens with Microsoft Word (only one `winword.exe` process exists and is associated with only one window title).

Is there any way I can list all the window titles of such applications through the command line?

Comment: [cmdow](http://www.commandline.co.uk/) shows some more entries.

Comment: Does this help: https://superuser.com/questions/378790/how-to-get-window-title-in-windows-from-shell ? See the answer with no AutoHotkey.

Comment: Thanks, both `cmdow` and `AutoHotkey` give me the window titles. I was hoping for a native solution without third party software though but I don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following PowerShell script:

```
Add-Type  @"
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Text;    
    public class Win32 {
        public delegate void ThreadDelegate(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);
        
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool EnumThreadWindows(int dwThreadId, 
            ThreadDelegate lpfn, IntPtr lParam);
        
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
        public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hwnd, 
            StringBuilder lpString, int cch);
        
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
        public static extern Int32 GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

        public static string GetTitle(IntPtr hWnd) {
            var len = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
            StringBuilder title = new StringBuilder(len + 1);
            GetWindowText(hWnd, title, title.Capacity);
            return title.ToString();
        }
    }
"@

$windows = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
Get-Process | Where { $_.MainWindowTitle } | foreach {
    $_.Threads.ForEach({
        [void][Win32]::EnumThreadWindows($_.Id, {
            param($hwnd, $lparam)
            if ([Win32]::IsIconic($hwnd) -or [Win32]::IsWindowVisible($hwnd)) {
                $windows.Add([Win32]::GetTitle($hwnd))
            }}, 0)
        })}
Write-Output $windows
```

I wrote a program that allows filtering this list and brings the selected window to the front: [activatewindow](https://github.com/mardukbp/activatewindow)

Comment: It works (not in PowerShell 2.0 though).